# Data isn't being passed to Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to pass value to a modal using the Bootstrap documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content). But for some reason the data isn't being passed.

Button to open modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var exampleModal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // Button that triggered the modal
  var button = event.relatedTarget
  // Extract info from data-bs-* attributes
  var recipient = button.getAttribute('data-bs-whatever')
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here
  // and then do the updating in a callback.
  //
  // Update the modal's content.
  var modalTitle = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-title')
  var modalBodyInput = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-body input')

  modalTitle.textContent = 'New message to ' + recipient
  modalBodyInput.value = recipient
})
```

I am using Bootstrap 5+ , and for whatever reason It requires data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target in order to open the modal.

Comment: Try changing `data-whatever="@mdo"` to `data-bs-whatever="@mdo"` **or** change `var recipient = button.getAttribute('data-bs-whatever')` to `var recipient = button.getAttribute('data-whatever')`

Answer (score 0):

You are using data-whatever instead of data-bs-whatever in the button.

Change that and everything will work fine. See below:

```js
var exampleModal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // Button that triggered the modal
  var button = event.relatedTarget
  // Extract info from data-bs-* attributes
  var recipient = button.getAttribute('data-bs-whatever')
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here
  // and then do the updating in a callback.
  //
  // Update the modal's content.
  var modalTitle = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-title')
  var modalBodyInput = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-body input')

  modalTitle.textContent = 'New message to ' + recipient
  modalBodyInput.value = recipient
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```